# Flow to pull name from email and put in a todo list

Tags: power-automate

How can I build a Microsoft flow to pull a name from an email and place it into a todo list/excel file to check off if I viewed the person or not. Example: different email received from mother everyday to add someone new to the invitation list. And place that person in a todo list or excel file. Different person in each email. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - create new flow with `When a new email arrives` trigger linked to your Outlook account. You can define specific e-mail address or e-mail subject to look for in your Inbox.

Then we assume that received e-mail contains only new person data which is `triggerBody()?['Body']`.

Crate some Excel sheet for eg. on your OneDrive account and put single column table inside. 
Finally `Add row into a table` action is needed.